# R Merge part of table into one column with sum

Tags: r

I have the following table in R:

```
  1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10  11  12  13  14  15  16  17  
162 148 108  93  67  83  44  53  37  47  25  34  17  22  11  11   5
```

I want to divide in into 7 parts had title of 1 2 3 4 5 6 7&greater, where it needs to combine all the number after 7 and merge it into the last one.

I have looked at aggregate & tapply but doesn't seem like the right function I need.

Comment: Can you show the code that you used to generate the above table?

Comment: ···result <- die_roll(6,1000) %>% table(.)··· die_roll is a function created to generate a list of required times for rolling to get number k with n times simulations

Answer (score 2):

```r
x <- c(x[1:6], "7 and above"=sum(x[-(1:6)]))
          1           2           3           4           5           6 7 and above 
        162         148         108          93          67          83         306
```

**data**

```r
x <- table(rep(c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17), c(162,148,108,93,67,83,44,53,37,47,25,34,17,22,11,11,5)))
```

Comment: Thank you! It works and I think I was struggling with trying to use some functions but ignore the simpliest way.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `table` to generate the output above you can use `pmin` to keep minimum between the values in your data and 7 and then use `table` to count the frequency.

Assuming your dataframe is called `df` and column name is `col_name` you can do.

```
tab <- table(pmin(df$col_name, 7))
```

The values under 7 would include all the 7 & above values together. You can rename it to make it more clear.

```
names(tab)[7] <- '7&above'
```